# Generacion del CAE y Consulta de datos del cliente

Tags: python, api

primero, quiero dar las Gracias de antemano a quien se tome el tiempo de echarme un cable, realmente estoy confundido.

Les comento, Soy desarrollador web, y me encargaron a efectos de prueba (no remunerados), montar una api que mediante JSONs y conexión Cliente(App de solicitudes) realice las peticiones mediante PHP a una api para resolver dos problemas específicos.

- Generación del CAE
- Obtención de los datos del cliente.

Ya se posee la factura solo, que la idea es mandar los datos del cliente a la api, y de la api a AFIP para que retorne un json con dichos datos y actualizar en la base local del Cliente.

Hasta aca todo bien, Soy desarrollador backend, y realmente no me es un problema realizar el trabajo, el chiste esta, en lo terminalmente engorroso y poco intuitivo que es trabajar con la documentación y los webservices de AFIP...

NO ENTIENDO ABSOLUTAMENTE NADA....

- No soy Argentino(He trabajado con facturación en México, chile, pero y otros paises), pero esto de verdad me esta consumiendo, no veo por que hacer una petición a de ser tan compleja, con tantos pasos y tan poco fácil de seguir.

No encuentro una guía o video que no me sobresature de información, ni términos fiscales que no me interesan, ocupo directamente un enlace, los headers y las peticiones, como una api clásica, pero en general, veo que para algo tan sencillo tengo que dar 4000 vueltas y ya estoy desesperada.

Entiendo que si esta compleja ah de ser por mi ignorancia o falta de experiencia, sobre la facturación Argentina, por eso, el dia de hoy, con la mano en el pecho y 1 semana sin dormir, vengo a pedir ayuda.

Ni siquiera se por donde comenzar. No estoy pidiendo que me hagan la chamba ni nada menos, quiero saber, si hay una guia o video mas enfocada en un inicio directo, y no pasando por teoría de facturación por que realmente NO ENTIENDO el sistema de facturación, ni tampoco los web service.

en función a lo que eh venido estudiando, interpreto que necesito ciertas cosas que se obtienen ingresando a la web de afis con la clave fiscal, el chiste es que la empresa no me quiere dar estos datos por ser datos sensibles, y me dicen que anteriormente no ha sido necesario... como les comento, desconozco, y en vista de la poca información que existe acudo a ustedes que se que tienen mas experiencia.

como se podrán imaginar, cai en esta apí investigando, pero, igualmente, estoy (aunque un poco menos) perdido, necesito ayuda antes de que me muera aca con la complejidad (que en este caso especifico, veo innecesaria).

Agradecería así, si alguien em podría guiar a entender como funciona esto, para aplicar las dos consultas que necesito, repito, no necesito que se me haga la chamba, solo que alguien bondadoso me explique como entrarle, algún a guía SIMPLE o video. o simplemente unos pasos generales, pero asertivos.

Tengo a la mano, las ganas de aprender, el agradecimiento,  la desesperación y 10 USDT por binance (no tengo dinero ya que soy estudiante) para quien me logre ayudar como tal.

Sin mas les deseo el mejor de los días, y muchas gracias.

En resumidas cuentas, Gracias.

Probé intentando entender la documentación oficial, pero es un desastre.

También intente usar PyAfipWs, pero es muy general y teórica a nivel de facturación, termine mas perdido que como empecé.

Comment: Lamento mucho tu situación. Sin embargo, probablemente tu pregunta quede cerrada por pedir recomendaciones de recursos externos. Te recomiendo recurrir a otro sitio y espero que encuentres a alguien que sepa del tema para ayudarte. Suerte!